# Issue in Excel SaveParser while appending data

Tags: regex, excel, perl, file, append

I want to create and then append some data in **excel file** using **perl** script. As advised on many forum links, I took reference from the *sample code* provided on [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) module link. The spreadsheet is created successfully and no issues with that.

But, then I use a second script to **append** some data to existing file. I use [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3A%3AParseExcel%3A%3ASaveParser) module and use the sample code provided on [this link](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3A%3AParseExcel%3A%3ASaveParser). Following is my code exactly same as the one provided on the site:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
  use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
  use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

  # Open an existing file with SaveParser
  my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
  my $template = $parser->Parse('perl.xls');


  # Get the first worksheet.
  my $worksheet = $template->worksheet(0);
  my $row  = 0;
  my $col  = 0;


  # Overwrite the string in cell A1
  $worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col, 'New string' );


  # Add a new string in cell B1
  $worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col + 1, 'Newer' );


  # Add a new string in cell C1 with the format from cell A3.
  my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row + 2, $col );
  my $format_number = $cell->{FormatNo};

  $worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col + 2, 'Newest', $format_number );


  # Write over the existing file or write a new file.
  $template->SaveAs('newfile.xls');
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Unknown method: Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Format::set_hidden at <path_to_SaveParser.pm> line 72.
```

I was left clueless since it threw error from a built-in module. Some **built-in function is not found**. Might be I have to import that module in my file (but don't know which one!). I think there is an issue with `SaveAs` subroutine. Following is a snippet from the module for reference:

```
sub SaveAs($$){
    my ($oBook, $sName)=@_;
    # Create a new Excel workbook
    my $oWrEx = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($sName);
    my %hFmt;

    my $iNo = 0;
    my @aAlH = ('left', 'left', 'center', 'right', 'fill', 'justify', 'merge', 'equal_space');
    my @aAlV = ('top' , 'vcenter', 'bottom', 'vjustify', 'vequal_space');

    foreach my $pFmt (@{$oBook->{Format}}) {
        my $oFmt = $oWrEx->addformat();    # Add Formats
        unless($pFmt->{Style}) {
            $hFmt{$iNo} = $oFmt;
            my $rFont = $pFmt->{Font};

            $oFmt->set_font($rFont->{Name});
            $oFmt->set_size($rFont->{Height});
            $oFmt->set_color($rFont->{Color});
            $oFmt->set_bold($rFont->{Bold});
            $oFmt->set_italic($rFont->{Italic});
            $oFmt->set_underline($rFont->{Underline});
            $oFmt->set_font_strikeout($rFont->{Strikeout});
            $oFmt->set_font_script($rFont->{Super});

            $oFmt->set_hidden($rFont->{Hidden});        #LINE 72 !!!

            $oFmt->set_align($aAlH[$pFmt->{AlignH}]);
            $oFmt->set_align($aAlV[$pFmt->{AlignV}]);
            if($pFmt->{Rotate}==0) {
                $oFmt->set_rotation(0);
            }
            #....
```

There doesn't seem any issue with the Shebang operator (`#!`) path, since it was the same path which I used while creating the excel file. Can anybody please provide some pointers about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Code works for me using perl 5.20.1 on ubuntu.  I used cpan to install `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` and `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`

Comment: Check your OS/Perl Version combo here : http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/S/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel.html http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/S/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel.html

Comment: The OS is SUSE Linux and perl version is 5.014001. But since the write to excel file takes place gracefully, I suspect very little about the version issue.

Comment: Which version of ParseExcel are you running?

Comment: The command `perldoc -m Spreadsheet::ParseExcel | grep VERSION` gives version: `our $VERSION = '0.59';.`

Comment: Version 0.59 has at least one known fail against perl 5.14.1 according to cpantesters.  Have you tried upgrading?  The latest version is 0.65.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll upgrade to newest version. Can you point to the link where the above issue might be reported?

Comment: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Spreadsheet-ParseExcel%200.59;os=linux;perl=5.14.1;reports=1

Comment: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Spreadsheet-ParseExcel

Comment: Thanks for the help.